# MIPS: how to store values into array

Tags: assembly, io, mips

I have coded the program to get 4 values from user and store it. However I can't figure out how to put it into the 'list' (.space):

```
.data 
list:  .space 16
msg: .asciiz "Enter 4 numbers: "
.text

main: 
la $a0,msg # display prompt string
li $v0,4
syscall

li $v0, 5 # read integer 
syscall
add $s0, $v0, $zero #store input1 to s0

li $v0, 5 # read integer 
syscall
add $s1, $v0, $zero #store input2 to s1

li $v0, 5 # read integer 
syscall
add $s2, $v0, $zero #store input3 to s2

li $v0, 5 # read integer 
syscall
add $s3, $v0, $zero #store input4 to s3




exit:    
    li $v0, 10 # exit system call 
sysca
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I can't figure out how to put it into the 'list'

By loading the base address of the array into some register, and then using the `sw` instruction to store data there:

```
la $a1, list

# ... read the integers ...

sw $s0, 0($a1)
sw $s1, 4($a1)
sw $s2, 8($a1)
sw $s3, 12($a1)
```

I suggest that you download *MIPS32™ Architecture For Programmers
Volume II: The MIPS32™ Instruction Set*.